# Extract elements from tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a tensorflow dataset containing all my data and labels.
The first 20 elements are extracted into another dataset using following code:

```
train_dataset = big_dataset.take(20)
```

But how do i extract for example the last 20 elements from big_dataset into a new dataset?

Thanks i advance!

EDIT:
The following code shows how i define the big_dataset:

```
big_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((all_points, all_labels))
```

What works now to get the first elemets is the following code (where train_size is e.g. 20):

```
train_dataset = big_dataset.take(train_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(train_size).map(augment).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

But using the .skip().take() results in an empty database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `skip`. For example, suppose you have 120 data samples and a batch_size of 1 and you have not shuffled your data, then you can try something like the following:

```
train_dataset = big_dataset.skip(100).take(20)
```

For your specific dataset, try:

```
import tensorflow as tf

samples = 29
all_points  = tf.random.normal((samples, 5))
all_labels  = tf.random.normal((samples, 1))
big_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((all_points, all_labels))
train_size = 20 
train_dataset = big_dataset.skip(9).take(train_size)
print(len(train_dataset))
```

```
20
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I have allready shuffeled my big_dataset. Using your technique the train_dataset seems to be empty.

Comment: Yes the dataset is empty because when you use skip and take..you are extracting batches of samples and not simply samples.. what is your batch size?

Comment: I have a batch size of 32. Why is the dataset not empty when only using e. g.  .take(20)?

Comment: My big_dataset contains 29 Arrays from 3 different classes

Comment: For the time beeing yes